# Auto Expand Product Category Tree

Tags: javascript, magento, extjs

I got stuck on this, basically what I need is a way to auto expand category tree node that contains a sub category node checked.

The entry point in the code is  `js/extjs/ext-tree-checkbox.js` and `'catalog/category/tree.phtml'`

It is possible to a expand a node in with `expand()` js method and it is no difficult to expand all node but this slow down the page too much.

**Update:**

I have tested the following solution:

1. Change `js/extjs/ext-tree-checkbox.js` render method adding this:

   ```
   var tree = n.getOwnerTree();
       if (tree){
           expandNodeIds =  tree.expandNodeIds.split(',');
           for (i in expandNodeIds) 
           {
               if (n.id == expandNodeIds[i])
                   n.expand();
           }
       }
   ```

This solution works but It breaks ( it is not displayed anymore ) the tree for permission Role

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix all the problem

```
 var tree = n.getOwnerTree();
    if (tree){
        expandNodeIds =  tree.expandNodeIds;

        if (expandNodeIds) {
            expandNodeIds = expandNodeIds.split(',');
            for (i in expandNodeIds) 
            {
                if (n.id == expandNodeIds[i])
                    n.expand();
            }
        }
```

Add the above code in `render` method of `js/extjs/ext-tree-checkbox.js`

Comment: Have you tested this? Where would you add it in the `render` method? Also, you seem to be missing a semicolon at the end. I've tested this in CE 1.7.0.2 and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: at that time, I have successful used it .. anyway It could be a good entry point for the solution, if you find any issue you can improve the answer or add a new one

Answer (score 4):

I did a little bug fixing and refactoring and packaged @obscures answer into a small extension. Give it a try on GitHub: [Kiwigrid_AutoExpandProductCategoryTree](https://github.com/kiwigrid/Kiwigrid_AutoExpandProductCategoryTree)

Answer (score 2):

Because:

```
 - Google sees this as a solution
```

My solution is in Php side, in class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Categories.

```
// start Added stuff
protected $_ubProductCategoriesParents;

public function getUbProductCategories()
{
    if (is_null($this->_ubProductCategoriesParents)) {
        $this->_ubProductCategoriesParents = array();
        $this->_ubProductCategoriesParents = array();
        foreach ($this->getCategoryIds() as $id) {
            $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
            $path = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')
                ->getAttributeRawValue($id, 'path', $storeId); // no model->load ever ever ever
            if (empty($path)) {
                $path = "";
            }
            $parentsIds = explode("/", $path);
            if (!(is_array($parentsIds) && count($parentsIds) > 0)) {
                $parentsIds = array();
            }
            $this->_ubProductCategoriesParents = array_unique(array_merge($this->_ubProductCategoriesParents, $parentsIds));
        }

        //Mage::log(print_r($this->_ubProductCategoriesParents, true));
    }

    return $this->_ubProductCategoriesParents;
}
// end Added stuff

// magento core function from class
protected function _getNodeJson($node, $level = 1)
{
    $item = parent::_getNodeJson($node, $level);

    if ($this->_isParentSelectedCategory($node)) {
        $item['expanded'] = true;
    }

    // added new if statement
    if (!(isset($item['expanded']) && $item['expanded'] == true) && array_search($node->getId(), $this->getUbProductCategories()) !== false) {
        $item['expanded'] = true;
    }

    if (in_array($node->getId(), $this->getCategoryIds())) {
        $item['checked'] = true;
    }

    if ($this->isReadonly()) {
        $item['disabled'] = true;
    }

    return $item;
}
```

Going now to have the above code in a rewrite class.

Thank you

Comment: The intro seems a bit out of place